# Расшифруйте код as3

Tags: actionscript

Стыдно после всего то, но что-то в голову ничего не лезет. Стр 285 книги Action Script 3.0 Шаблоны проектирования:

```
var child:DisplayObject = this.getChildAt(i);
localDamage += IPlane(child).getDamage();
```

Не знаю, может, нужен связанный код, если достаточно и этого, просветите, что это вообще за вызов, дисплей обжекта через интерфейс? Я просто синтаксис понять не могу. Что за интерфейс, скобки, объект? Как это читается? В смысле `trace(IPlane(child))` чего там выдаст и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это попытка приведения экземпляра объекта к интерфейсу.

То есть подразумевается, что класс объекта реализует этот интерфейс.

Если попытка будет удачная, то будет вызван метод `getDamage()`.

Если нет, выпадет с ошибкой, что неправильно, на мой взгляд, нужна проверка приведения к типу.

```
if ( child is IPlane) localDamage += IPlane(child).getDamage();
```

`trace(IPlane(child))` - читается как попытка вызвать `toString()` у экземпляра `IPlane`, если приведение к типу сработало. Если нет выдаст "null". Если экземпляр `IPlane` не реализует `toString`, то выдаст что-то вроде `Object a56ed4f Sprite` или еще какой верхний класс экземпляра.